# ServiceNow create a script to add a field to a form

Tags: servicenow

I am currently trying to add a field to a form design programatically.  I have already declared a column on the Base Configuration Item (cmdb) table and am now trying to find out how to add that field to children of that table programatically.  I am already able to go into each child's form design and and drag the field in because I have already added it as a column on the base table but I would like to know how to write a script that places a field in a form design so that I can do it for multiple children and fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same view name, adding the field to the parent table should cause it to trickle down to all child tables. 
In order for this to work, you'll want to do this via **Configure>Form Layout**, not the Form Designer.

More info here:  https://community.servicenow.com/thread/169202